# Why does my horizontal separator line disappear when I add a horizontal scroll view?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, scrollview

I am using android studio to create an app. App works but the layout doesnt work with small screens properly. So first I added a vertical scroll view, the 5 horizontal separator lines show up. Then I added a horizontal scroll view, now the 5 horizontal separator lines do not show up. Why is this? I do not know how to make them show up with the horizontal scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".30" />
   //Current resources------------------------------------------------
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CurrentTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CURRENT"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MetalIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Metal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/CurrentTitle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalCounter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/MetalCounter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/MetalCounter" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WoodIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wood"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/MetalCounter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/WoodCounter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/WoodCounter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/WoodCounter" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/FoodIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Food"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/WoodCounter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/FoodCounter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/FoodCounter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/FoodCounter" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MetalCounter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/MetalIcon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/WoodIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/WoodCounter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/WoodIcon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/FoodIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/FoodCounter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/FoodIcon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/SeparatorLine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/MetalCounter" />
    //Resource Income--------------------------------------------------
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IncomeTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="INCOME"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalIncomeIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SeparatorLine"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine2" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MetalIncomeIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Metal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/MetalIcon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/MetalIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SeparatorLine"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine2" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WoodIncomeIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Wood"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/MetalIncomeResult"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/WoodIncomeResult"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SeparatorLine"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine2" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/FoodIncomeIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Food"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/WoodIncomeResult"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/FoodIncomeResult"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SeparatorLine"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MetalIncomeResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/WoodIncomeIcon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/MetalIncomeIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/SeparatorLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WoodIncomeResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/WoodIncomeIcon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/FoodIncomeIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/SeparatorLine"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/FoodIncomeResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/FoodIncomeIcon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/SeparatorLine"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine2" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/SeparatorLine2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/MetalIncomeResult" />

   //Metal resource camps and upgrades--------------------------------

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MetalCamp1Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Camp 1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/MetalCampSubmitButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalCamp1Counter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/MetalCamp1Counter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/MetalCamp1Counter" 
   />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MetalCamp2Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Camp 2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/MetalCamp1Counter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalCamp2Counter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/MetalCamp2Counter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/MetalCamp2Counter" 
   />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MetalCamp3Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Camp 3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/MetalCamp2Counter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalCamp3Counter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/MetalCamp3Counter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/MetalCamp3Counter" 
   />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MetalCamp1Counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/MetalUpgrade1Counter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/MetalUpgrade1Counter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/SeparatorLine2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/MetalUpgrade1Counter" 
   />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MetalCamp2Counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/MetalUpgrade2Counter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/MetalUpgrade2Counter"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/MetalCamp2Icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SeparatorLine2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MetalCamp3Counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/MetalUpgrade3Counter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/MetalUpgrade3Counter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SeparatorLine2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/MetalUpgrade3Counter" 
   />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MetalUpgrade1Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upgrade 1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/MetalCampSubmitButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalUpgrade1Counter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/MetalUpgrade1Counter"
            
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/MetalUpgrade1Counter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MetalUpgrade2Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upgrade 2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/MetalUpgrade1Counter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalUpgrade2Counter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/MetalUpgrade2Counter"
             
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/MetalUpgrade2Counter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MetalUpgrade3Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upgrade 3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/MetalUpgrade2Counter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalUpgrade3Counter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/MetalUpgrade3Counter"
            
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/MetalUpgrade3Counter" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MetalUpgrade1Counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/MetalUpgrade1Icon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalUpgrade2Icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MetalCamp1Counter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine3" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MetalUpgrade2Counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/MetalUpgrade2Icon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalUpgrade3Icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MetalCamp2Counter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine3" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MetalUpgrade3Counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/MetalUpgrade3Icon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MetalCamp3Counter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/SeparatorLine3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MetalCampSubmitButton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Metal Icon"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/MetalCamp1Icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SeparatorLine2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/SeparatorLine3" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/SeparatorLine3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/MetalUpgrade1Counter" 
   />

   //Wood resource camps and upgrades---------------------------------
        <View
            android:id="@+id/SeparatorLine4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/WoodUpgrade1Counter" 
   />

   //Food resource camps and upgrades---------------------------------

        <View
            android:id="@+id/SeparatorLine5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/FoodUpgrade1Counter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/BuyingSubmitButton" />
   //Things to buy----------------------------------------------------
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BuyingSubmitButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BUY"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/TechCardsPlusButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SeparatorLine5"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ResourceCampsPlusButton" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TechCardsIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tech Cards"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/SeparatorLine5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ResourceCampsIcon" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AirshipsIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Airships"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/CatapultsIcon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
        //Things to buy values---------------------------------------------
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TechCardsCost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="M: 0  W: 0  F: 0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/TechCardsMinusButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/SeparatorLine5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ResourceCampsCost" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AirshipsCost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="M: 0  W: 0  F: 0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/AirshipsMinusButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/CatapultsCost"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
  //Things to buy buttons--------------------------------------------
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TechCardsMinusButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/TechCardsCost"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/TechCardsCounter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/SeparatorLine5"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ResourceCampsMinusButton"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TechCardsCounter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/TechCardsMinusButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/TechCardsPlusButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/SeparatorLine5"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ResourceCampsCounter"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TechCardsPlusButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/TechCardsCounter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/BuyingSubmitButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/SeparatorLine5"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ResourceCampsPlusButton" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AirshipsMinusButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/AirshipsCost"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/AirshipsCounter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/CatapultsMinusButton"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AirshipsCounter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/AirshipsMinusButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/AirshipsPlusButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/CatapultsCounter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AirshipsPlusButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/AirshipsCounter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/BuyingSubmitButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/CatapultsPlusButton"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you provide your layout code?

Comment: I was trying not to. But just did. I this is only about 1/2 the layout though because the post is limited to 30 thousand characters. Hopefully you can follow this. I can post a picture if needed.